# S3 getObject Pre-signed url generated from lambda not working

Tags: python-3.x, amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, aws-lambda, pre-signed-url

I have the following lambda which gets triggered upon uploading a file a to bucket and sends it's pre-signed URL to an API.

```
import urllib3
import boto3
import json
import urllib

def lambda_handler(event, context):

    headers = {
        'Content-Type': "application/json",
        'Accept': "*/*", 'Accept-Encoding': "gzip,deflate,br",
        'Connection': "keep-alive"
    }

    http = urllib3.PoolManager()

    bucket = event['Records'][0]['s3']['bucket']['name']
    key = urllib.parse.unquote_plus(
        event['Records'][0]['s3']['object']['key'], encoding='utf-8')
        
    preSignedUrl = boto3.client('s3').generate_presigned_url(
        ClientMethod='get_object', Params={'Bucket': bucket, 'Key': key}, ExpiresIn=3600)

    params = {
        "url": preSignedUrl,
        "file_name": key.split("/")[-1]
    }
    
    print("Request params: ", params)

    url = "http://abcdefg.io/file"
    
    try:
        r = http.request("POST", url, body=json.dumps(params), headers={
                    'Content-Type': 'application/json'})
        print("Response: ", r.data)
    except Exception as e:
        print(e)
```

This is generating pre-signed URLs but I am not able to access files using that. When I type the URL in a browser, I get the following,

```
<Error>
   <Code>AccessDenied</Code>
   <Message>Access Denied</Message>
   <RequestId>ESAB5DBZCTGX1JEW</RequestId>
 <HostId>C/aB8l0LL3C3ifAzuvcWBz89mTV1MkYHsYGXvlzgLQvVnqEvrea+KCfIbBUUOBSgYJ+PX+2kyh8=</HostId>
</Error>
```

I tried generating the URL from cloud shell with the command `aws s3 presign <s3-url>`. And the URLs generated by this are working fine. So what is the issue here? Why am I getting access denied?

I added,

```
client = boto3.client("s3",region_name=<my-region>, aws_access_key_id=<my_access_key>, aws_secret_access_key=<my_secret_key>)
```

and generated the presigned URL again. And newly generated URLs worked. So the issue is with the client. It is not working without specifically mentioning the keys. I remember generating pre-signed URLs without specifying keys in lambda code. So what is the real issue here?

Comment: Where and how do you use your `preSignedUrl`?

Comment: I use this presigned URL to download a file using my program,

Comment: My program is working. I tested with the manually generated presigned URL and it worked. Issue is when generating the URL using lambda. I am getting access denied.

Comment: My guess is that the IAM role assigned to the Lambda function doesn't have PutObject permissions against the relevant folder.

Comment: I am the root user. So that shouldn't be an issue, right? Also, I have edited the question slightly ( added access and secret keys specifically for the client and it worked. ). Please check that as well

Comment: The Lambda function will only run with the permissions assigned to it, so these permissions need to be correctly defined.  Something like:

    {
      "Action": [
        "s3:GetObject",
        "s3:PutObject"
      ],
      "Resource": "[bucket-arn]/*",
      "Effect": "Allow"
    }

Comment: Also, you shouldn't need to specify the access key and secret within the Lambda function in that way as it will run using the permissions of the role assigned to it.  In fact, it's bad practise to surface your keys in that way (anyone who sees your code will have access) and you should avoid using them and defer to IAM roles unless necessary.

Comment: @Norman So, the code is fine right? also Where do I have to specify this? { "Action": [ "s3:GetObject", "s3:PutObject" ], "Resource": "[bucket-arn]/*", "Effect": "Allow" }

Comment: It's specified in a policy used by the execution role within the Lambda function.  If you're in the AWS console, you can navigate to your Lambda function, go to Configuration/Permissions and you'll see the execution role.  You can navigate to that role within IAM then assign PutObject and GetObject to the relevant S3 bucket's objects using the ARN of the S3 bucket followed by '/*' to specify all objects.  The UI lets you define that using a wizard or specifying the JSON directly.  What I provided was what (part of) it would look like if specified using JSON.

Answer (score 2):

The issue seems to be very likely arising from the policy attached/associated with the execution role of the lambda in the context here. So for the resolution, if you add an inline policy to the role's permission (as below) then the lambda should be able to generate working pre-signed URLs.
If you using AWS management console, then you can navigate to the lambda role's permission via lambda function -> Configuration (4th tab) -> Permissions (3rd from top in left menu) -> click on Role name. This will take you to the role's summary page where you can modify the policy.

Inline policy:

```
{
"Version": "2012-10-17",
"Statement": [
    {
        "Sid": "VisualEditor0",
        "Effect": "Allow",
        "Action": [
            "s3:GetObject",
            "s3:ListBucket"
        ],
        "Resource": "*"
    }
]
```

}

A simpler version of generating an S3 pre-signed URL from lambda (with appropriate permission) might look like this (in JavaScript):

```html
var AWS = require('aws-sdk');
var s3 = new AWS.S3({
  signatureVersion: 'v4',
});


exports.handler = (event, context, callback) => {
  const url = s3.getSignedUrl('getObject', {
    Bucket: '<bucket name>',
    Key: '<path to object in bucket>',
    Expires: 1000,
  });


  callback(null, url);
};
```

Answer (score 0):

In Labmda, since you don't use access keys, it assumes a role through its IAM policy (STS). This means that for each call it generates temporary credentials with short expiry and uses them to execute whatever it needs (in this case, pre-signing a URL).

When actually downloading/uploading from the client-side, you need to send `'X-Amz-Security-Token'` in the body with the value you get when pre-signing. Unfortunately this is not clearly documented by AWS.

In PHP it was

```
$credentials = $s3client->getCredentials()->wait();
$sessionToken = $credentials->getSecurityToken();
```